# I got an error while executing django-admin startproject newDjango as invalide syntax

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
(newDjango) C:\Python34\Scripts\newDjango>C:\Python34\Scripts\newDjango\Scripts\django-admin.exe startproject newDjango .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\newDjango\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\scripts\newdjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "c:\python34\scripts\newdjango\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
  File "c:\python34\scripts\newdjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 12
    return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to run the latest version of Django on Python 3.4. It doesn't support Python 3.4 - you need 3.5 or higher.

Comment: install django 1.11 LTS its the last to support python2 and also will support python3.xx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.4, then make sure you have Django 2.0 installed. 
With python 3.4, Django 2.1x throws the above error.

Run the command to install django: 
`pip3 install Django==2.0.0`

Verify the version:

```
$ python -m django --version
2.0

$ python -V
Python 3.4.0
```

This should resolve your issue.